# How to move subcaptions to left side for vertical subfigures

Tags: subcaption

How can I move the subcaptions to the left side when I have a vertical subfigure arrangement. eg:

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
     \centering
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.6\textwidth}
         \centering
         \subcaption[]{}
         \includegraphics[trim={0 2cm 0 2cm},clip,width=\textwidth]{img/MeltPoolPack115.eps}
         \label{fig:115}
     \end{subfigure}
     \hfill
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.6\textwidth}
         \centering
         \subcaption[]{}
         \includegraphics[trim={0 2cm 0 2cm},clip,width=\textwidth]{img/MeltPoolPack95.eps}
         \label{fig:95}
     \end{subfigure}
     \hfill
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.6\textwidth}
         \centering
         \subcaption[]{}
         \includegraphics[trim={0 2cm 0 2cm},clip,width=\textwidth]{img/MeltPoolPack75.eps}         
         \label{fig:five over x}
     \end{subfigure}
        \caption{Three plots}
        \label{fig:75}
\end{figure}
```

looks like this (What I am trying to do in red):

[image]

Comment: You can put two minipages inside the subfigure, or you can use two subfigures.  It helps to know the widths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This version uses two subfigures per row.  A subfigure is basically just a minipage, although it also affects `\caption`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \setlength{\parskip}{\floatsep}% add spacing between images
    \begin{subfigure}[c]{1cm}
         \caption[]{}
         \label{fig:115}
     \end{subfigure}
     \begin{subfigure}[c]{0.6\textwidth}
         \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
     \end{subfigure}
    
    \begin{subfigure}[c]{1cm}
         \caption[]{}
         \label{fig:95}
     \end{subfigure}
     \begin{subfigure}[c]{0.6\textwidth}
         \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
     \end{subfigure}
     
     \begin{subfigure}[c]{1cm}
         \caption[]{}
         \label{fig:five over x}
     \end{subfigure}
     \begin{subfigure}[c]{0.6\textwidth}
         \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-c}
     \end{subfigure}
    
     \caption{Three plots}
     \label{fig:75}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```